# How to read data from a file into a 1-D array of structures

Tags: arrays, printing, struct, structure

I'm working on my c++ program assignment and I can't wrap my head around how to read data in from a file into a 1-d array of structures.  My data file looks like this:

01 Jimmy Johnson
190 60

02 Gerald Hill
180 56

The first number being their id, the next to words being their first and last names, and the next line is their height and weight.  My teacher wants me to read this data into an array "Astronaut".  And THEN somehow put the correct info into "NAME" and "BODYSTATS", using a 1-D array of structures, so I can correctly print the information later.  I've only gotten as far as reading data into a single array and printing it.  How in the heck do I assign certain words in the array to certain (structs?) and be able to print them later?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

struct ob
{
  string name;
  string id;
  int height;
  int weight;
};

int main()
{
  ob p[100];
  string emptyline;
  int count=-1;
  ifstream input("data.txt");
  while (input>>p[++count].id)
  {
     getline(input, p[count].name);
     p[count].name = p[count].name.substr(1);
     input>>p[count].height>>p[count].weight;
     getline(input, emptyline); // \n after weight
     getline(input, emptyline); // empty line
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Okay, so can you tell me exactly what happens after your while statement (the getline line and the next 4-5 lines)

Comment: this keeps read from file until endoffile. we got id then the name by getline and removed the space after the id from the name. got weight and height. then read the endofline after the weight. because that dont get read when reading int. then we got the empty line......